# Executing SQL Script using OSQL do not return resultcode

Tags: installation, inno-setup, osql

I am executing some sql queries using `OSQL` through inno setup. I am using following code to run `OSQL`. This is just for example purpose

```
SQLQuery:= '"EXEC sp_addserver ''PCNAME'';"';
Param:= '-S(local) -Usa -Psa -Q ' + SQLQuery;
Exec('osql.exe', Param, '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

This works fine. The problem is `ResultCode` value is always 0. Even if the query does not get executed. For example if I try same query like below where I pass in an invalid stored procedure name the `ResultCode` is still 0.

```
SQLQuery:= '"EXEC sp_invalidname ''PCNAME'';"';
Param:= '-S(local) -Usa -Psa -Q ' + SQLQuery;
Exec('osql.exe', Param, '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

Why don't this return me a proper code. If I run the second query in management studio I get an error like this

`Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
Could not find stored procedure 'sp_invalidname'`

Here return code is `2812`. Why dont I get this when I run it through inno. What do I need to do to get this error code in inno?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to TLama, I updated my code as below and its working now. I had to add `-b` command line parameter and now it returns 1 if the command fails.

> -b
>   Specifies that osql exits and returns a DOS ERRORLEVEL value when an error occurs. The value returned to the DOS ERRORLEVEL variable is 1 when the SQL Server error message has a severity of 11 or greater; otherwise, the value returned is 0. Microsoft MS-DOS batch files can test the value of DOS ERRORLEVEL and handle the error appropriately.

I updated my code as below.

```
Param:= '-S(local) -Usa -Psa -b -Q ' + SQLQuery;
```

Its explained in the [*documentation*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162806.aspx).

Comment: Ah, the `-Q` must be followed by the query. I've put the parameter on the wrong place.

Comment: Yeah. My fault didn't notice it before. Thanks though.